# How to install KDE / Qt / Plasma themes without the full Plasma package?

Tags: kde, qt, theme, plasma, kate

How do I install KDE / Qt / Plasma themes without installing the full (rather big) Plasma package?

Or specifically in my case: How do I install a Dark theme for Kate editor?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on apps and their Themes support, installing Qt themes might be enough.

For example, to have a Dark theme in `kate`, install:

```
apt install breeze breeze-gtk-theme  # Ubuntu
pacman -S breeze breeze-gtk  # ArchLinux
```

After that, you can choose the theme from Kate itself:[image: screenshot of picking Dark theme in Kate]

Installing a Theme configurator such as qt5ct [discussed here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1088255/64255) can also help, but it might not be as good as a Qt-specific theme. For example, Kate will keep some surfaces White even in a Dark theme with qt5ct.